# UIImageView rotation affecting position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, accelerometer, uiaccelerometer

I have a UIImageView that is set to move up and down the screen with the value of the accelerometer, using the following code:

```
ship.center = CGPointMake(ship.center.x, ship.center.y+shipPosition.y);
```

Where `shipPosition` is a CGPoint set in the accelerometerDidAccelerate method using:

```
shipPosition.y = acceleration.x*60;
```

Obviously this works fine, it is very simple. I run into trouble when I try to something equally simple, vary the rotation of the image depending on its acceleration. I do this using:

```
ship.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(shipPosition.y);
```

For some reason this causes a very strange thing to happen, in that the image snaps back to its origin every time the main method is called. I can see frames where the image moves to where it should be, but then instantly snaps back.

This problem only happens when I have the rotation line in, commented out it works fine. I have no idea what is going on here, I have done this many times for different apps and i never had such a problem. In fact I copied my code from a different app I created where it works fine.

**EDIT:**

What *really* confuses me is when I change the angle of the rotation from the acceleration to the position of the ship using:

```
ship.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(ship.center.y/10);
```

When I do this, the ship actually rotates based on the accelerometer but does not move, which is crazy because a changing `ship.center.y` means the position of the ship is changing, but it's not!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the *transform* of you view back to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` before you set his center coordinates or frame and after that apply the new transformation.

The `frame` property returns the transformed coordinates of a view if it is transformed and not the *true* (well actually the transformed are true) coordinates.

Quote from the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW5):

> Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

---

**Update/Actual Answer:**
Well the actual problem is

```
shipPosition.y = acceleration.x*60;
```

Since you set the y pos in `accelerometerDidAccelerate`.
The `acceleration` won't remember it's old value. So if you move your device it will get a peak and as you slow down it will decelerate again.

Your ship will be +/-60 at the highest acceleration speed but will be 0 when you stop moving your device and `shipPosition.y` will be 0.

Comment: So what you're saying is I apply the rotation, then write "ship.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;", and then change move the object? I just tried that there, the object doesn't move or rotate now.

Comment: No. I assume you have a game loop or a timer where you apply the new coordinates and the rotation. The should look like: 1. apply new coordinates 2. transform. The new should look like: 1. apply identity 2. apply new coordinates 2. transform.

Comment: Yes I have a loop, and I did what you just said there, but I am getting the same problem as always, i.e. the image is rotating but not moving.

Comment: I've upped my answer after i realized that you use device motions.

Comment: No, because the code works just fine without the transformation part! If I just use it without rotating it works exactly as expected! There is something strange happening with the transformation

Answer (score 0):

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation expects angle in radians, not in degrees.

1 radian = M_PI / 180.0 degrees

Comment: True, at the end of the day that;re just numbers, it can't distinguish between them. If it goes over 2pi radians, it just loops back over the circle again, just as if it exceeds 360deg. It is irrelevant